# SQL-Command: How do i get distinct value out of multiple lines?

Tags: sql

i have a a table like this:

```
 X    Y     Number     Value   
asd   xcv   1111         A1
ads   xvc   1111         A1
qwe   rtz   2222         A2
qew   zrt   2222         A2
```

I want to have a Query that references to Number but gives me as a result just ONE Line/Cell with Value. Sth. like:

```
select * 
from datatable
where number = "..." 
-->gives me value ONCE
```

in my opinion it´s no "distinct-command"-issue, but i hope you´ll understand what i mean.

Comment: What's your expected result?

Comment: i expect from the query a line like that: `"1111    A1"`.
But what i get so far is this line two times.. but this gives me an error in my procedure.. so i need to get rid of the "doubled" line.

Comment: Number 1111 exists in two rows, but you only want one of them? How to decide?

Comment: yes correctly! but i don´t know how to do this!

Comment: Does a specific number always have the same value for each row?  Then simply do `SELECT DISTINCT Number, Value FROM...`.

Comment: What's your DBMS? If you want all columns there's e.g. Standard SQL ROW_NUMBER, PostgreSQL supports DISTINCT ON.

Comment: i didn´t ask precisely, so of course you all are right, but my problem seems to be sth. else.. so it´s another topic. Thank you all for the quick responds and you´re all right!

Comment: If you want to get the whole records, then I think you will always get more than 1 value returned, since the X and Y fields with 1111 are different. You should further explain what you need

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to eliminate duplicates use **DISTINCT**

```
SELECT
DISTINCT Number,Value  FROM table
```

***[SAMPLE HERE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c6c9b2/8)***

Comment: yes i didn´t know how to ask my problem precisely, so yes your solution is correct of course ;)!

Answer (score 4):

Try something like

```
SELECT DISTINCT Number,Value
FROM YourTable
WHERE Number='1111'
```

Another approach was to use `SELECT TOP 1 FROM ...` but this smells...

And one more approach

```
SELECT Number,Value
FROM YourTable
WHERE Number='1111'
GROUP BY Number,Value
```

Comment: BTW I'm confused with the question when I answered it. This is the correct answer to your problem @Mattis Seehaus

Comment: The WHERE clause might not even be needed in this case

Comment: @PrinceJea Thx for supporting me :-) You've got the acceptance :-) Nvm, that's life and happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DISTINCT dt.Number,dt.Value
FROM dbo.datatable dt
WHERE number = "1111"
```

Comment: Are you sure about the `dt.*`?

Comment: @Shnugo - Sorry, my mistake.. :/

Answer (score -2):

You can use [GROUP BY](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-group-by.htm) command. It will remove all duplicate values.

```
select * 
from datatable
GROUP BY Value;
```

Comment: yeah i´m trying this out, but not working so far.. i´ll respond if it worked ;)

Comment: This one will not work since there are no records for which all colunns are unique ;-)

Comment: @MattisSeehaus I did not ask you, but Black Bird... This will simply not return the expected result due to the `SELECT *` ...